# Scrapy - AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run scrapy from a single python script http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/practices.html

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "single_python_script.py", line 16, in <module>
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.spidercls.update_settings(self.settings)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
```

Comment: Which Scrapy version are you using? I guess you have the latest version... you can look this up with `scrapy version`. If this is the case refer to the latest documentation instead of 0.24

Comment: Well actually what you said is correct! I'm using the latest version and looking at the wrong documentation. Thank you

Comment: @GHajba, care to turn your comment into a response?

Comment: @Gallaecio I don't see any reason to do so. My comment is not an answer just a hint where to find the cause of the error. imo.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Scrapy 1.0 you should use `CrawlerProcess` instead of `Crawler` to run a Scrapy spider from a script.

See the [latest documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) for more information.